# Where are GDB symbols coming from?

Tags: linux, gdb, symbols, elf

When I load Fedora 28's `/usr/bin/ls` file into GDB, I can access to the symbol `abformat_init`, even if it is not present as a string nor in the symbols table of the binary file.

```
$ file /usr/bin/ls
/usr/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d6d0ea6be508665f5586e90a30819d090710842f, stripped, too many notes (256)
$ readelf -S /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
$ nm /usr/bin/ls
nm: /usr/bin/ls: no symbols
$ strings /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
$ gdb /usr/bin/ls
[...]
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ls...Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ls...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install coreutils-8.29-7.fc28.x86_64
(gdb) info symbol abformat_init 
abformat_init in section .text of /usr/bin/ls
```

Where does this symbol comes from? Is there a program that allows to extract them outside of GDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR:

1. There is a special `.gnu_debugdata` compressed section in Fedora binaries that GDB reads, and which contains [mini-symbols](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/MiniDebugInfo).
2. Contents of that section can be conveniently printed with `eu-readelf -Ws --elf-section /usr/bin/ls`

---

> `readelf -S /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat`

That command is dumping *sections*. You want *symbols* instead:

```
readelf -s /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
readelf --all /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
```

> `strings /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat`

Strings tries to guess what you want, and doesn't output all strings found in the binary. See [this blog post](https://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2014/10/psa-dont-run-strings-on-untrusted-files.html) and try:

```
strings -a /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
```

**Update:** I confirmed the results you've observed: `abformat` does not appear anywhere, yet GDB knows about it.

Turns out, there is a `.gnu_debugdata` *compressed* section (described [here](https://gnu.wildebeest.org/blog/mjw/2016/02/02/where-are-your-symbols-debuginfo-and-sources/)), which has [mini-symbols](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/MiniDebugInfo).

To extract this data, normally you would do:

```
objcopy -O binary -j .gnu_debugdata /usr/bin/ls ls.mini.xz
```

However, that [is broken](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23947) on my system (produces empty output), so instead I used `dd`:

```
# You may need to adjust the numbers below from "readelf -WS /usr/bin/ls"
dd if=/usr/bin/ls of=ls.mini.xz bs=1 skip=151896 count=3764
xz -d ls.mini.xz
nm ls.mini | grep abformat
```

This produced:

```
00000000000005db0 t abformat_init
```

QED.

Additional info:

1. Confusing GDB `no debugging symbols` is addressed in [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19551).
2. `objcopy` refusing to copy `.gnu_debugdata` is the subject of [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23947).
3. There *is* a tool that can conveniently dump this info:

   `eu-readelf -Ws --elf-section /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
    37: 0000000000005db0    593 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT       14 abformat_init`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seems to work either:
```$ strings -a /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat
$ readelf -a /usr/bin/ls | grep abformat```

Comment: @JonathanHussey I think I solved the puzzle. Answer updated.

Comment: @JonathanHussey I've updated the answer once more: there is an easy way to get to this info.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a program that allows to extract them outside of GDB?

Yes, you can use `nm` to extract the symbol, but you should look for the symbol in a separate debug info file, because the binary itself is stripped.

You can use `readelf` or `objdump` to know separate debug info file name, see [How to know the name and/or path of the debug symbol file which is linked to a binary executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42750115/72178):

```
$ objdump -s -j .gnu_debuglink /usr/bin/ls

/usr/bin/ls:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .gnu_debuglink:
 0000 6c732d38 2e33302d 362e6663 32392e78  ls-8.30-6.fc29.x
 0010 38365f36 342e6465 62756700 5cddcc98  86_64.debug.\...
```

On Fedora 29 the separate debug info file name for `/usr/bin/ls` is `ls-8.30-6.fc29.x86_64.debug`.

Normally, on Fedora, separate debug info is installed to `/usr/lib/debug/` directory so the full path to debug info file is `/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/ls-8.30-6.fc29.x86_64.debug`.

Now you can look for the symbol with `nm`:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/ls-8.30-6.fc29.x86_64.debug | grep abformat_init
0000000000006d70 t abformat_init
```

Note that separate debug info should be installed with `debuginfo-install`, this is what gdb is telling you.

Comment: It's trivial to know where `abformat_init` comes from when the debuginfo is installed. The puzzle here is to figure out how GDB knows about `abformat_init` when debuginfo is *not* installed.

Comment: This is what I don't understand also, I am only answering the question. GDB should not know about `abformat_init` because of `(no debugging symbols found)...done`.

Comment: And weird gdb output should be fixed in https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19551.